# How to spawn enemies with a randomized speed

Tags: c#, random, unity-game-engine, spawning

I would like to know how to spawn enemies with a randomized speed. I've looked around on the Internet looking for solutions, but none of them seem to come close (or maybe I haven't looked hard enough, I'm not sure. If there's a solution somewhere out there, please do share it).

It'd also be great if I could have the randomized speeds beginning after a certain time has passed since the start of the game.

I currently have the following code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SpawnEnemies : MonoBehaviour {

//Variable to store the enemy prefab
public GameObject Enemy;
//Array to store the spawn points
public Transform[] SpawnPoints; 
//Variable to countdown the time for each spawn so that more enemy prefabs can spawn
public float SpawnTimer = 5.0f;

//Variable to store amount of original enemies spawned at the start of the game
private int nEnemies = 1;
//Variable to store the previous spawn time
private float prevSpawnTime = 1f;
//Variable to store the spawn delay time
private float delay = 0f;

//List to store the number of spawn points
List<int> spoints = new List<int>();

//Update called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //Variable to store the delayed spawn time, where the delayed spawn time equals to the current time since the game has started minus the previous spawn time
    float dt = Time.time - prevSpawnTime;
    //If the delayed spawn time is more than the spawn delay time
    if (dt > delay) 
    {
        //Call the SpawnEnemy() function
        SpawnEnemy();
        //Randomize the spawn delay time, between 2 to 5 seconds
        delay = Random.Range (2, 5);
        //Initialize the previous spawn time back to the current time
        prevSpawnTime = Time.time;
    }
}

//Function to spawn new enemies
void SpawnEnemy()
{
    //Decrease the SpawnTimer each time one enemy prefab is spawned
    SpawnTimer -= 1;

    //If 10 enemies are spawned and the number of current enemies spawning each time is less than 5
    if (SpawnTimer % 10 == 0 && nEnemies < 5) 
    {
        //Current number of enemies spawning each time +1
        nEnemies++;
    }

    //Clear the List of spawn points
    spoints.Clear ();
    //Insert a number between 0-4 (the spawn points) starting at 0 into the List of spawn points
    spoints.InsertRange (0, new int[]{0,1,2,3,4});

    //As long as there are at least one enemy spawning at each time
    for (int i = 0; i < nEnemies; i++) 
    {
        //Variable to randomly store the spawn position
        int idx = Random.Range(0, spoints.Count-1);
        //Initialize the randomly stored spawn position into the List of spawn points
        int pos = spoints[idx];
        //Remove the randomly stored spawn position from the List so that no other enemy prefabs can spawn from that position
        spoints.RemoveAt(idx);
        //Instantiate the enemy prefab at the randomly stored spawn position
        Instantiate (Enemy, SpawnPoints [pos].position, SpawnPoints [pos].rotation);
    }
}
```

}
`

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

```
using System.Random rand;

    void Start()
    {
    rand = new System.Random();
    }

    public IEnumerator SpawnAtRandTime()
    {
      while(true)
     {        
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(rand.Next(0,100));
       SpawnEnemy();
     }
    }
```

This should work just fine. Just use `StartCoroutine(SpawnAtRandTime())` in some loop. When you want to stop spawning enemies call StopCoroutine().